# Datarange Float32 xyz-values in pointcloud2 for kinect

Tags: kinect, rosbag, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I'm working to get the data values of the xyz components out of the pointcloud2 in a bagfile made from kinect with openni_kinect. I was wondering however what the datarange for these values are, to be able to see if my results make any sense. Are these values in meters (so 3.4 for 3.4m) or different?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10945/datarange-float32-xyz-values-in-pointcloud2-for-kinect/) by [Marco](https://answers.ros.org/users/920/marco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 77 on 2011-08-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes the units are meters. The standard units are defined in [REP 103](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html)

If anything does not comply with REP 103 it should be heavily documented at all levels to avoid confusion.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-08-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2